# How to become the gini-index for each possible first split using CART in R (package rpart)

Tags: r, cart, rpart, gini

I have a huge Dataset with more than 125 variables.

I am applying a CART (Classification and regression tree). What I am missing is a list of all possible first splits, with the referring gini-values (If you apply a CART in SAS, you become such a list by default).

Does anybody has an idea how to become such a list?

Best Regards and thank you for your help,

Samuel